# Creating nested list for elements with same counts

Tags: python-3.x, nested-lists

Here's an example list:

```
['hello', 'hell', 'hel', 'he', 'h', 'he', 'hell', 'hello', 'hel', 'hello', 'hell']
```

so how would i go about making a nested list for the elements with the same amount of counts? To be more clear, nesting the elements together that appears the same amount of time in a list. Output would be like this:

```
[['hello','hell'], ['hel', 'he'], ['h']]
```

Because the count of [hello,hell] is 3 so they are together like the rest of the elements in the list

Comment: What is the "count" of a word?

Comment: The amount of time an element appears in the list @trincot

Answer (score 2):

With some imports it could be done like this:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby

words = ['hello', 'hell', 'hel', 'he', 'h', 'he', 'hell', 'hello', 'hel', 'hello', 'hell']

counts = Counter(words)
res = [list(group) for _, group in groupby(counts, key=lambda k: counts[k])]
```

`res` will be:

```
[['hello', 'hell'], ['hel', 'he'], ['h']]
```